# SQL: Return records containing a word where the last letter is anything except K

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, wildcard

Suppose I have a table containing a column by the name "Query". I have to display the records where the string in this column has used `noloc` instead of `nolock`. Note that `noloc` can be followed/preceded by `)` or space etc. I just need all records that have anything before and after `noloc` except nolock. Is there a way to do it in SQL?

I tried:

```
select * from table1
where Query LIKE '%noloc%'
```

but this includes queries containing `nolock`. I tried variations of the above like putting space before and/or after `%` but none of them fills all the criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want anything + noloc + any one char but k + anything. Here:

```
select * from table1
where Query LIKE '%noloc[^k]%'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use both conditions in the where clause

```
select * from table1
where Query LIKE '%noloc%' and Query NOT LIKE '%nolock%'
```